# Character wrong action after collision unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision, rigid-bodies

I have a character (moved with the keyboard's arrows). I have several walls on my house.

The thing is, I wanted to detect collisions when I go against a wall (so it won't go through). It's ok. But now, when my character goes against a wall, he does weird things, he moves alone like he was in a gravity mode (I don't know if understandable).

So, I'd like that, when I go against a wall, character stops moving ? I've tried a lot of things and I'm kinda lost atm so if you have any idea I'll take it and try ! Just for the record,started using unity a few months ago, so there might errors in my script ( I mean, it compiles but maybe its not written the best way).

Here's my script :

```
public class ScriptCharacter : MonoBehaviour
{
private Animator m_animator;
private Rigidbody m_rigidBody;
private void Start()
{
    m_animator = gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>();
    m_animator.SetFloat("Speed", 1);

}

// Update is called once per frame
private void FixedUpdate()
{
    float v = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
    float h = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    transform.Translate(transform.forward * v * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
    transform.Rotate(0, h * Time.deltaTime * 30, 0);
    m_animator.SetFloat("Speed", v);
}
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    Debug.Log("here");
    if (collision.gameObject.name == "Wall")  
    {
        m_rigidBody.velocity = Vector3.zero;
        m_rigidBody.angularVelocity = Vector3.zero;
        m_animator.SetFloat("Speed", 0);
    }
}


}
```

Comment: I tried that, and froze rotation axes as well and it worked ! thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Chestera mentioned in the comments:

Set the rigidbody to kinematic in  `onCollisionEnter()` and set it back to dynamic in `onCollisionExit()`.

From the Unity docs, "If isKinematic is enabled, Forces, collisions or joints will not affect the rigidbody anymore."

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-isKinematic.html